# make ssh command output to monitor

Tags: command-line, ssh, opengl

I am trying out the Jetson Nano (think an Ubuntu 18 for AI stuff) and I am running into this issue.

[image]
As you can see from screenshot, I got both an SSH session and a noMachine remote desktop into the box.

In the above picture, when I run: [camera detection](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/blob/master/docs/detectnet-camera-2.md) and have to execute this command:

> ./detectnet /dev/video0                # V4L2 camera

via the remote desktop it works.
If I do it via the ssh terminal it fails.

Like here: [image]
The error is at OpenGL trying to create the display, which makes sense. It is trying to do it over an SSH session.

```
bounding box 1  (325.916412, 19.095182)  (1243.184204, 700.690735) 
w=917.267822  h=681.595581 [OpenGL] glDisplay -- set the window size
to 1280x720 [OpenGL] creating 1280x720 texture (GL_RGB8 format,
2764800 bytes) Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My question is, when I run the command over SSH, how do I force the output to be displayed on the NoMachine desktop?

Or rephrased another way, I want to execute the commands over ssh but have the video results displayed on the remote desktop.

---

added picture of what if I use: export DISPLAY=":0.0"
[image]

Comment: What happens if, in your ssh session, you type `export DISPLAY=":0.0"` and then try the commands. If this does not work, try again but use the output of `echo $DISPLAY` in a local terminal in place of `:0.0` above.

Comment: it works better, at least it doesn't core dump anymore. but output is still not seen on the desktop. $DISPLAY is :0.0. I have added the picture to the original question to show what I am looking at